# Compiling using cmake with dependencies installed using macport

Tags: opencv, compilation, cmake

I'm trying to build project that has dependency to OpenCV. I installed Opencv using macports and when I try to build project, cmake gives the following output:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I searched a little bit about this problem and added the following env. variables to my `$HOME/.profile` file

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/local
```

without success. I checked and I have all opencv files istalled in /opt/local/lib and /opt/local/include/opencv directories. There is also  `OpenCVConfig.cmake` in the following path:

`/opt/local/lib/cmake/OpenCVConfig.cmake`

How to make cmake know the path where opencv is installed? Previously I've build OpenCV on my own using cmake and installed  into /usr/local and then it worked fine without any other fix. However I had some problems with ffmpeg and right now I switched to using macports.

Answer (score 9):

Another option that works for me was set the env value OpenCV_DIR at the cmake opencv dir:

```
export OpenCV_DIR=/opt/local/lib/cmake/
```

Answer (score 1):

**macports** traditionally installs OpenCV to `/opt/local/` instead of the standard `/usr/local/`.

The solution to your problem is stated at:

> Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>     "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.

When building your project in the command-line, make sure you execute:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/local/lib
```

And then set the flag `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` for cmake:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/local ../
```

Comment: Sorry about that, but that's usually how I solve this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not a MACPORT problem, but someone may find this helpful. Followed @hugh-pearse 's and @leszek-hanusz 's answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711109/could-not-find-module-findopencv-cmake-error-in-configuration-process/22239942#22239942), with a little tweak. I had installed ***opencv from ubuntu 12.10 repository (libopencv-*)*** and had the same problem. Couldn't solve it with `export OpenCV_DIR=/usr/share/OpenCV/` (since my OpenCVConfig.cmake whas there). It was solved when I changed some lines on the OpenCVConfig.cmake file:

```
# ======================================================
# Include directories to add to the user project:
# ======================================================

# Provide the include directories to the caller

#SET(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/include/opencv;${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/include")

SET(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS "/usr/include/opencv;/usr/include/opencv2")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# ======================================================
# Link directories to add to the user project:
# ======================================================

# Provide the libs directory anyway, it may be needed in some cases.

#SET(OpenCV_LIB_DIR "${OpenCV_INSTALL_PATH}/lib")

SET(OpenCV_LIB_DIR "/usr/lib")

LINK_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_LIB_DIR})
```

And that worked on my Ubuntu 12.10. Remember to add the `target_link_libraries(yourprojectname ${OpenCV_LIBS})` in your CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 1):

I finally read the header of the OpenCVConfig.cmake file.
It instructs to include these lines to use from an external project:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(MY_TARGET_NAME ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

(adding include_directories to CMakeLists.txt fixed it for me)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have compiled OpenCV, once you compiled, OpenCVConfig.cmake will be generated in build directory.

follow [these](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) steps to compile

then , `export OpenCV_DIR=<path to build directory with OpenCVConfig.cmake>`

It should work now !

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above ideas in vain.
I eventually found a way to have the compilation work: Besides using @kengregson steps, I simply renamed the folder /usr/local/include/opencv2 so that it is not chosen when compiling my cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

Since I compile my own OpenCV in a multiple-users server, so I can't install the OpenCV libs in /usr/local directly, but in my home folder instead, then exactly the same issue occurs to me.

Below is how I fix it:

1. Flowing the steps in [OpenCV official doc: Using OpenCV with gcc and CMake](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.2/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#linux-gcc-usage)
2. Add displayImage test program, and use this CMake file

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV)
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )`

3. The same error happened, so add one environment variable in my .tcshrc

`setenv OpenCV_DIR "${folder where contains OpenCVConfig.cmake }"
\# mine is:
setenv OpenCV_DIR "~/local/OpenCV2.4.13/share/OpenCV"`