# How to install ConvNet library?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I am trying to install ConvNet library, which is implementing data propagation throught convolutional neural networks, but i got this error. How to repair this?

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBCV
    linked by target "testimg" in directory /home/damian/trunk
    linked by target "testmnist" in directory /home/damian/trunk
LIBHIGHGUI
    linked by target "testimg" in directory /home/damian/trunk
    linked by target "testmnist" in directory /home/damian/trunk
```

Answer (score 0):

CMake has logic to find libraries on your system, and `NOTFOUND` is the expected outcome of that logic if you're actually missing those libraries. So, obviously you just install OpenCV including OpenCV-HighGUI.

Comment: I might have misremembered. The necessary functionality is [not shipping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711109/could-not-find-module-findopencv-cmake-error-in-configuration-process) with CMake, but with OPenCV itself/