# FindOpenCV.cmakeConfig.cmake

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to Unix and trying to get OpenCV running on a Raspberry Pi.
Have copied a file called FindOpenCV from github and installed that in usr/shared/OpenCV and now get a message from the interpreter saying it can't find FindOpenCV.cmakeConfig.cmake.

Been going through the stuff on the internet for 4 days now and no further ahead.  Can anyone help a complete beginner please.
Thanks in anticipation.
NeilK

Comment: If you just want to build programs using OpenCV, you shouldn't need anything from the git repository - just install `libopencv-dev` and compile your sources with `CFLAGS+=$(pkg-config --cflags opencv)`.  Link them with `LDLIBS+=$(pkg-config --libs opencv)`.

Answer (score 1):

This file should be installed as part of OpenCV installation along with many other files. You need to **install** OpenCV, not pick random files from the repo. How to do it depends on what OS your Pi board is running.

Comment: Thanks but I've installed OpenCV and the only FindOpenCV file on the computer is the one I downloaded from github and put in /usr/share/OpenCV.  It was the stackoverflow advice at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711109/could-not-find-module-findopencv-cmake-error-in-configuration-process.  My OS is Linux 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP arm7l GNU/Linux Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus).