# How can I use cmake's find_packge(OpenCV) on gitlab

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, gitlab

I am using cmake to compile a c++ and OpenCV project. and I want to run my tests on Gitlab but got some errors. My question is:  How can I use **find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)** in CMakeLists.txt on gitlab? this is my CMakeLists.txt: (by the way, it works correct locally on my Linux machine .)

```
# cmake minimum requiredments
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)

# project name 
project(imageEnhancer LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF) # disable compiler specific extensions
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Catch2 QUIET)
if (NOT Catch2_FOUND)
  message("Catch2 not found")
  include(FetchContent)

  FetchContent_Declare(
      catch2
      GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
      GIT_TAG        v2.11.0
  )

  FetchContent_MakeAvailable(catch2)
  list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${catch2_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib")
endif()


# search for OpenMP
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

# search for OpenCV
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )


# add a library to the project using the specified source files
add_library(opencv STATIC include/opencvtest.h src/opencvtest.cpp)


# PUBLIC -> targets that link to this target get that include directory
target_include_directories(opencv PUBLIC include PRIVATE src)

# link to the imported target provided by the FindOpenMP moudule
target_link_libraries(opencv PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)

# Create executable with name imageEnhancer
add_executable(imageEnhancer main.cpp)

# linke to the imported target provided by the FindOpenMP module 
target_link_libraries(imageEnhancer PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

but I got the following error:

```
$ cd project
$ mkdir -p build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Catch2 not found
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")  
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:
    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/builds/davood_hadiannejad/algorithm-engineering-lab/project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

and I tried to solve it like, but it didn't work

```
if (NOT Catch2_FOUND)
  message("Catch2 not found")
  include(FetchContent)

  FetchContent_Declare(
      OpenCV
      GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
   
  )

  FetchContent_MakeAvailable(OpenCV)
  list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib")
endif()
```

any suggestion?  thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `HINTS` with find_package to tell CMake where it should look.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26193046/5520012) might help